# How to include database file in controller CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I want to make a central database file with all the database functions. I've made a libraries file, called `Database.php`. I've load the file in the `__construct` function in the controller of one of my modules, on this way:

`$this->load->library('Database');`

But when i want to try to make in that controller a get function, it will say this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Bikes::get()

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your library's method like this..

1.Load library

```
$this-load->library('library_name');
```

2.Call to method

```
$this->library_name->method_name();
```